# problem in python script for phone call from skype account

Tags: python, skype4py

I'm trying to do a phone call by python script from skype account. It runs properly sometime while sometime give segmentation error while sometime it runs without error but no output. I had used following script for this as,

```
import Skype4Py
import sys
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
skype.Attach()
m_PhoneNumber = "919763667993"
m_Call = skype.PlaceCall(m_PhoneNumber)
```

Please give me solution for this, i think it maybe Skype4Py.api.posix_dbus.SkypeAPI Thread Problem ,
but not getting solution for this.

Comment: I wasn't able to find an exact answer to the problem but it looks like there is a thread handling issue in OSX if that happens to be your platform: [here is a link to a patched rep](https://github.com/stigkj/Skype4Py#readme "Github repo")

Comment: The skype API requires that the number is in the users contacts.